# C- reading a multi-line file with fgets or sscanf?

Tags: c, file-io

lets say for example i have a text file

```
person1
25
500
male
person2
..
..
..
person3
..
```

with however many number of people, and i want to read in 4 lines of the file into a struct for each person in the file.

How can I do this? I have tried just using multiple fgets, but I don't know how I can loop until the end of the file while reading four lines at a time

Thanks

Comment: Please can you show your attempt. You will be able to tell from the return value of `fgets` whether end of file has been reached.

Comment: Here is the only place not using `fgets()/sscanf()` but using `scanf()` instead makes sense. `scanf()` will skip whitespace. So you can simply do  `if (scanf ("%[^\n]%d%d%[^\n]", ... vars ...) == 4) { /* store in struct */ }`. Your read will be fragile and dependent on the 4-line repetition holding -- but  it provides a simple read of multiple lines. (you should also include a *field-width* modifier before each string conversion to protect your storage bounds, e.g. `"%63[^\n]"` to limit the read to 63-chars (+1 for `'\0'`) for a 64-char array used as storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment above, when you have a fixed repeating set of lines in a data file that you need to read into a `struct`, this is one of the only exception where you should consider `scanf()/fscanf()` over the recommended `fgets()/sscanf()` of each line.

*Why?*

`scanf()` is a *formatted input function* (compared to `fgets()` which is a *line-oriented input function*). If you have formatted input that spans multiple lines, `scanf()/fscanf()` ignore *whitespace* (the `'\n'` character being *whitespace*) and will allow you to consume multiple lines as a single input (with a properly crafted *format-string*)

When using `scanf()/fscanf()` to read data into a string (or array), you must use the *field-width* modifier to limit the number of values read into your array to avoid writing beyond the end of your array invoking *Undefined Behavior* if an input exceeds your array bounds. This applies whenever you use `scanf()/fscanf()/sscanf()` (the entire family). Use without a *field-width modifier* to read array data is no better than using `gets()`.

So how to craft your *format-string*? Let's look at an example struct with 4-members similar to what you show in your question, e.g.

```
...
#define MAXG 8      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXP 32
#define MAXN 128

typedef struct {    /* struct with typedef */
    char name[MAXN], gender[MAXG];
    int iq, weight;
} person;
...
```

With your data as shown, and with the declaration for `name` being `128` characters and that for `gender` being `8` characters and the remaining two members being `int` types, you can do something similar to the following:

```
    int rtn;                                /* fscanf return */
    size_t n = 0;                           /* number of struct filled */
    person ppl[MAXP] = {{ .name = "" }};    /* array of person */
    ...
    while (n < MAXP &&  /* protect struct array bound, and each array bound below */
            (rtn = fscanf (fp, " %127[^\n]%d%d %7[^\n]", /* validate each read */
                    ppl[n].name, &ppl[n].iq, &ppl[n].weight, ppl[n].gender)) == 4)
        n++;            /* increment array index */
```

Looking specifically at the *format string*, you have:

```
    " %127[^\n]%d%d %7[^\n]"
```

where `" %127[^\n]"`, by virtue of the leading `' '`, consumes any leading whitespace, then reads at most `127` characters (you cannot use a variable or macro to specify *field-width*), the characters are any character in the line that is NOT the `'\n'` character (allowing you to read whitespace as part of the name, e.g. `"Mickey Mouse"`).

Note the `"%[...]` is a string conversion and will read any character in the list of characters `[...]` as a string. Using the circumflex `'^'` as the first character of the list *negates* the match resulting in `"%[^\n]"` read all characters not including the `'\n'` into a string.

The space before `" %[^\n]"` is required because `"%[...]"` like `"%c"` are the only *conversion-specifiers* that do not consume *leading whitespace*, so you provide for that by including a space before the conversion in your format string. The other two conversion specifiers for `int`, e.g. `"%d"` will consume leading whitespace on their own resulting in the total conversion:

```
    " %127[^\n]%d%d %7[^\n]"
```

That, in summary, will:

- consume any leading whitespace (the `'\n'` left in `stdin` from the prior read or of `gender` for the previous struct in the array);
- read a line up to 127-characters into the `name` member with `%127[^\n]`;
- readi the line containing the first integer value into `iq` with `%d` (which consumes leading whitespace);
- read the line containing the second integer value into `weight` with `%d` (ditto);
- `' '` consume the `'\n'` left from the read of `weight`; and finally
- read a line up to 7-characters into the `gender` member with `%7[^\n]` (adjust as necessary to hold your longest gender string)

With that approach you can consume 4-lines of input into each struct in an array with a single call to `fscanf()`. You should check `rtn` on loop exit to ensure the loop exited on `EOF` after reading all values from the file.  A simple check will cover the minimum validation needed, e.g.

```
    if (rtn != EOF) /* if loop exited on other than EOF, issue warning */
        fputs ("warning: error in file format or array full.\n", stderr);
```

(**note:** you can also check if `n == MAXP` to see if the reason for loop exit was due to the array being full separately).

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXG 8      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXP 32
#define MAXN 128

typedef struct {    /* struct with typedef */
    char name[MAXN], gender[MAXG];
    int iq, weight;
} person;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int rtn;                                /* fscanf return */
    size_t n = 0;                           /* number of struct filled */
    person ppl[MAXP] = {{ .name = "" }};    /* array of person */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (n < MAXP &&  /* protect struct array bound, and each array bound below */
            (rtn = fscanf (fp, " %127[^\n]%d%d %7[^\n]", /* validate each read */
                    ppl[n].name, &ppl[n].iq, &ppl[n].weight, ppl[n].gender)) == 4)
        n++;            /* increment array index */

    if (rtn != EOF) /* if loop exited on other than EOF, issue warning */
        fputs ("warning: error in file format or array full.\n", stderr);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  /* output results */
        printf ("\nname   : %s\niq     : %d\nweight : %d\ngender : %s\n",
                ppl[i].name, ppl[i].iq, ppl[i].weight, ppl[i].gender);

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

(**note:** you can also use a global `enum` to define your constants as well)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/ppl.txt
person1
25
500
male
person2
128
128
female
Mickey Mouse
56
2
male
Minnie Mouse
96
1
female
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readppl dat/ppl.txt

name   : person1
iq     : 25
weight : 500
gender : male

name   : person2
iq     : 128
weight : 128
gender : female

name   : Mickey Mouse
iq     : 56
weight : 2
gender : male

name   : Minnie Mouse
iq     : 96
weight : 1
gender : female
```

You can also read each line with `fgets()` using either a line-counter or multi-line read approach, but this is more about choosing the proper tool for the job. There is nothing wrong with using `fgets()` and then multiple calls to `sscanf()` for the integer values or two calls to `strtol()` for the conversion, but with large input files, 1-function call to `fscanf()` compared to 4-separate calls to `fgets()` plus 2-separate calls to `sscanf()` or `strtol()` plus the additional logic for handling your line-counter or multi-buffer logic will start to add up.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Some example lines.  I'll leave you to supply the rest of the program.

```
#define MAX 1000

  ...

  FILE *f;
  char line1[MAX], line2[MAX], line3[MAX], line4[MAX];

  ...

  while(fgets(line1, MAX, f) != NULL)
    {
      if (fgets(line2, MAX, f) == NULL ||
          fgets(line3, MAX, f) == NULL ||
          fgets(line4, MAX, f) == NULL)
        {
         /* insert code here to handle end of file in unexpected place */
          break;
        }
      /* insert code here to do your sscanf and anything else you want */
    }

    ....
```